# to change font color int the textbox for a certain range of number

Tags: vb.net

basically I want to enter a number in the textbox. if the number is grater than 80 the number should be in red color and when  I re-enter another number which is less than 80 then the font color should be black.

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. Show the code you've tried so far and specifically where you're having an issue.

Comment: Use the TextChanged event

Answer (score 0):

You have double check first if you are typing a number to don't get exception, Here is how you need to proceed after adding your textbox1:

```
'The event that handle text change
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim myInteger As Integer
    'first check if your textbox1 value is a valid integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, myInteger) Then
        'use if ... else to check the value
        If myInteger > 80 Then
            ' give the color
            TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here the code is supposing that you are looking for an integer not a decimal, and you said :

> is grater than 80 ... ...another number which is less than 80

what about = 80 ?

Comment: Good answer but a new user will never learn to ask a good question if we answer bad quality questions.